# logging in using cookie authentication/authorization in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, session

How safe is Cookie based Authentication/Authorization in ASP.NET C#? Take a look at the example below, don't worry about password hashing, All this code does is that it takes a username and a password and lets a user login. After they login, I have multiple pages that use the role for authorization purposes. is this a secure/semi-secure method, or sufficient enough to prevent attacks and exploits against a web application? would you change anything in this code?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _context.UsersTableTest.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == Username);

        if (user != null && user.PasswordHash == Password)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim("UserDepartment", user.UserDepartment) // Assuming you have a Department property in the user model
        };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                // Set additional properties if needed
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties);

            return RedirectToPage("/Index"); // Redirect to a protected page
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this code that you wrote and/or maintain?

Comment: Yes, this code is what I wrote and maintain.

Comment: `UsersTableTest.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == Username)` You expect more than one person to have the same username? `FirstOrDefault` should be used in extremely rare cases IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var user = await _context.UsersTableTest.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == Username);
```

Please bear in mind that `==` operator are case sensitive. Depending on the database setup it might be okay to use like this. I just wanted to highlight under some circumstances it might return `null` due to case sensitivity.

---

```
if (user != null && user.PasswordHash == Password)
```

You have a giant `if`-`else` block inside your method. Both of them returns an `IActionResult`. So, either move the code from the `else` block to the same level as the `if` and then delete the empty `else` block. Or you can reverse the condition and guard only the error path, something like this

```
if (user == null || user.PasswordHash != Password)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return Page();
}

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    new Claim("UserDepartment", user.UserDepartment) 
};
...

return RedirectToPage("/Index");
```

BTW1: where do you define/receive the `Password`?
BTW2: why don't you pass the password hash as well to the linq query?

---

```
var claims = ...
var claimsIdentity = ...
var claimsPrincipal = ...
```

I haven't used the built-in authentication feature of ASP.NET for a while but I think you could rely on it (`HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync`) for this simple use case rather than hand crafting every single piece.

---

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
```

You might need to set the Principal to the `HttpContext` as well (`HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal;` prior to the call of `SignInAsync`.

Comment: Thank you. I am receiving the password through an input label, and I set the variables to them, look at the example below.



        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }